# react redirect not working when some routes are inside a custom component

Tags: reactjs

[Live preview](https://stackblitz.com/github/goodmite/react-issue1)

I have a simple routing stragary.

1. for /login -> show LoginPageContainer
2. for /register -> show LoginPageContainer again
3. for / -> redirect to /login
4. for * -> show NotFoundPage

If all routes are at same level everything works fine.

```
      <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                {/*<App />*/}
                <Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                <Route path={'/register'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

But If login and register routes are inside `App` component, **/ and * routes show nothing.**

**Index.js**

```
           <Switch>
                <App />
                {/*<Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>*/}
                {/*<Route path={'/register'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>*/}
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
```

**App.js**

```
render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                        <Route path={'/register'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

---

Full code

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { store } from './helpers';
import { App } from './App';
import { configureFakeAPI } from './helpers';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import {NotFoundPage} from "./components/NotFoundPage";
import LoginPageContainer from "./components/LoginPage";
configureFakeAPI();

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <App />
                {/*<Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>*/}
                {/*<Route path={'/register'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>*/}
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Redirect to="/login" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { PrivateRoute } from './PrivateRoute.js';
import { history } from './helpers';
import { alertActions } from './actions';
import { HomePage } from './components/HomePage';
import LoginPageContainer  from './components/LoginPage';
import { RegisterPage } from './components/RegisterPage';
import './styles.css';
export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        history.listen((location, action) => {
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { alert } = this.props;
        return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <Route path={'/login'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                        <Route path={'/register'} component={LoginPageContainer}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes you mentioned show nothing, I believe, because `<Switch/>` only expects `<Route/>` inside of it, and is looking to match the current location to those routes. But you're feeding it `<App/>` which makes it always return that and stop.

You either need to put `<App/>` itself in a `<Route/>` inside of the switch or take it outside, and maybe use another `<Switch/>` for the nested routes in the component.